# How do I successfully console log the data from this api?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I go into the Network tab and inside response, I do get the results of this API, but I cannot get it to output in the console.

This is the code:

```
const NAMEURL = "https://uzby.com/api.php"

// get data from api
function getDataFromApi(value, callback){
  const QUERY = {
    min:`${value}`,
    max:`${value}`
  }
  $.getJSON(NAMEURL, QUERY, callback)
}

function renderResult(result){
  return `${result}`;
}

// render results to page
function displayName(data){
  console.log(data);
  const results = renderResult(data);
  $('.nameResult').html(results);
}

// wait for user to submit
function watchSubmit() {
  $('.js-search-form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const queryTarget = $(event.currentTarget).find('#js-dropValue');
    const thisquery = queryTarget.val();
    getDataFromApi(thisquery, displayName);
  });
}
// running the watch submit function waiting for click
$(watchSubmit);
```

I tried doing a `console.log(getDataFromApi())` but I get undefined in console.

Comment: you are `console.log`ing in `displayName` aren't you?

Comment: by chance, are you seeing an error in the browser console, something to do with access-control headers missing?

Comment: `getDataFromApi` doesn't return anything. Not sure if ajax calls in jQ are async, but regardless, the function returns nothing and willk  always console log undefined

Comment: @JaromandaX, I am getting the access-control headers missing

Comment: well, that's your problem - that site doesn't want to share it's resources directly with your web page - you'll need to proxy that request through your own server, the one that loads your page

Comment: @JaromandaX, I have no idea how to do that, do you have some documentation I could look at?

Comment: depends on what server side language is available ... it's a fairly easy thing to search for "*your server side language* proxy"

Comment: @JaromandaX, well, okay, if you want to post all this as an answer I will check it off. Thank you.

Comment: no need for this to be an answer, if you look for CORS issues in stack overflow, you'll see it's been addressed thousands of times - some of those questions may provide help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log(getDataFromApi());` would never work, its `displayName()` that you would have to console log.

Your code was not wrong, with the exception of what you were trying to console log, but even then its not going to work because uzby does not want to share its resources directly with your application.

So indeed that error you were getting, the CORS error is the problem.

You need to proxy that request through your own server, the one that loads your page. You will have to research documentation on your server side language proxy. A potential solution for your code could be like this:

```
xmlhttp.open(
    'GET',
    'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://example.com/api.php?' + param,
    true
  );
```